# plotting huge data data in x-axis

Tags: plot, performance-testing

I am working on simulator in JAVA...I am sending thousands of requests to my SERVER and get the responses i want to plot the response times of these thousands of requests indivisually on JFreechart but i am unable to decide how to plot the response times of these huge amout of requests...Say i have 10,000 requests sent to my server and server processes each request and send the response Now how i will plot 10,000 response times....X-axis is labeled with Req#1,Req#2,Req#3...and so on....y-Axix is labled with Time(miliseconds) .....Kidly help  me

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to see the individual response times?  If summary data is sufficient, then you could create a [SimpleHistogramDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/SimpleHistogramDataset.html) with appropriate bins for the response times (for example, 0.0 - 0.5 secs, 0.5 to 1.0 secs, 1.0 to 1.5 secs and so on) then add the individual response time data to the dataset as it comes in.  Once the data is added to the dataset, you can plot a histogram showing the distribution of response times.  The [ChartFactory.createHistogram()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createHistogram%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method will help with creating the chart.

Comment: ok i will now start studying SimpleHistogramDataset as i am unaware of this class ,after learning this i will try to do this and if i found any problems i will ask u again,,,bundle of fnx!

Comment: I have done what u taught me but i come up with another problem, since i also want to compare the performance of different tuning strategies equipped in the server and now i got more than one SimpleHistogramDataset objects i.e Strategy1 sent me 1000  responses and strategy2 also sent me 1000 responses now how i will draw more than one SimpleHistogramDataset objects in a single graph to compare the performance...if it is not possible then waht would be the atlernative